# How to calculate average time

Tags: javascript, algorithm, datetime, time

how to calculate average time with 11:59:00 PM and 12:00:00 AM so that it can be 11:59:30 PM. currently this code is giving me 11:59:30 AM

```
       var convertTimeToMilliSecondsTest = function(time) {
                  var startDate = "1970/01/01";                         
       if(time.indexOf("AM") != -1) {
          newTime = time.replace("AM", " AM");
       } else if(time.indexOf("PM") != -1) {
          newTime = time.replace("PM", " PM");
       }
          var dateString = startDate + " " + newTime;
          var date = new Date(dateString.replace(/-/g, '/'));                                 
          return date.getTime();
       }

         var calculateAverageTimeToBed = function(dataset) {
                 var totalTimeInMilliSeconds = 0;

                 for(var i = 0;i < dataset.length; ++i) {
                       totalTimeInMilliSeconds += convertTimeToMilliSecondsTest(dataset[i].startTime);
                 }

                 var averageTimeInBed = totalTimeInMilliSeconds / dataset.length;

                 return averageTimeInBed;
          }
```

Comment: That's because 12:00:00 AM is the start of the day, not the end of it. You need to add one day to it to make the math work. Alternatively, use 11:59:59 PM instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function for if you are looking for an average time given a set of times, regardless of date, given a 24 hr period. It works for 12am - 12pm but not 12pm - 12am (because that spans 2 days). If you are spanning days, you must use my first answer which requires the entire date be given in the time being evaluated.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X93yp/)

```
// function will determine average time given a set of 
// times in a 24 hr. period, i.e. 12am - 12pm
// it does NOT work for a 24 hr. period from 12pm - 12am
var times = ['11:59:00 AM', '12:00:00 AM'];

// function accepts an array of times as the argument
// requires time to be structured as above
function getAverageTime(times) {
    var count = times.length
    var timesInSeconds = [];
    // loop through times
    for (var i =0; i < count; i++) {
        // parse
        var pieces = times[i].split(':');
        var ampm = pieces[2].split(' ');
        var hrs = Number(pieces[0]);
        var mins = Number(pieces[1]);
        var secs = Number(ampm[0]);
        var ampm = ampm[1];
        // convert to 24 hr format (military time)
        if (ampm == 'PM') hrs = hrs + 12;   
        // find value in seconds of time
        var totalSecs = hrs * 60 * 60;
        totalSecs += mins * 60;
        totalSecs += secs;
        // add to array
        timesInSeconds[i] = totalSecs;
    }
    // find average timesInSeconds
    var total = 0;
    console.log(timesInSeconds);
    for (var j =0; j < count; j++) {
        total = total + Number(timesInSeconds[j]);
    }
    var avg = Math.round(total / count);
    console.log('avg secs: '+avg);
    // turn seconds back into a time
    var avgMins = Math.floor(avg/60);
    var avgSecs = avg - (60 * avgMins);
    var avgHrs = Math.floor(avgMins/60);
    console.log('hours: '+avgHrs);
    avgMins = avgMins - (60 * avgHrs);
    // convert back to 12 hr. format
    var avgAmpm = 'AM';
    if (avgHrs > 12) {
        avgAmpm = 'PM';
        avgHrs = avgHrs - 12;
    }
    // add leading zeros for seconds, minutes
    avgSecs = ('0' + avgSecs).slice(-2);
    avgMins = ('0' + avgMins).slice(-2);
    // your answer
    return avgHrs+':'+avgMins+':'+avgSecs+' '+avgAmpm;
}

// execute
alert(getAverageTime(times));
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the entire date (with days) in your calculation. Here is one way to do it:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8pxz/)

```
var date1 = '2013-09-17 11:59:00 PM';
var date2 = '2013-09-18 12:00:00 AM';

var d1msecs = new Date(date1).getTime(); // get milliseconds
var d2msecs = new Date(date2).getTime(); // get milliseconds

var avgTime = (d1msecs + d2msecs) / 2;
console.log(avgTime);

var result = new Date(avgTime);
alert(result);
```

Comment: How can this give you 11:59:30 PM if say the date2 variable is changed to "2013-09-21 12:00:00 AM" ?

Comment: In what sense do you mean "average time"? Are you looking for the middle point between two times? That's the sense I was looking at it in.

Comment: Yes it is average time but when you change the day in the date object i'm getting a different average time depending on the date.

Comment: Yes because the code I added finds the middle point between 2 times... I think what you are looking for though is the average time from a set of times... let me add another answer.

Comment: To others facing this problem, if you are trying to find an average of two times from Date objects then if it is solely the time that you are interested in (finding the average of the time elements of the date object regardless of the actual date) then simply set the date of both variables to a common date.. e.g. '2000-01-01 hh:mm:ss'. you can use the .SetFullYear() method on the vars to change that.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, so I though I'll post a snippit this using [Aidan Sheriff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2734263/aidan-sheriff)'s comment of SetFullYear().  It will return average time (Hours, Minutes and Seconds) of all dates with Today's date.

```js
let dateArray = [new Date('Sat Oct 15 2016 07:09:00 GMT+0800 (MYT)'), new Date('Mon Oct 17 2016 06:48:00 GMT+0800 (MYT)'), new Date('Tue Oct 18 2016 08:38:00 GMT+0800 (MYT)')];

function getAverageTime(array) {
  let sum = 0;
  array.map(function(d) {
    let now = new Date();
    let startDay = d.setFullYear(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
    sum += startDay;
  });

  return new Date(sum / dateArray.length);
}

console.log(getAverageTime(dateArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for the following:
[23:30, 00:30, 01:30] you'd like a result of 00:30 then the following is for you:

```
const ONE_DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS = 24 * 3600 * 1000;

function calculateAverageOfHours(times, minTime){
  let timestamps = times.map(getTimePartInMilliseconds);
  let minTimestamp = getTimePartInMilliseconds(minTime);
  
  let average = 0;
  timestamps.forEach(t => {
    average += getMillisecondsFromTimeTillMinTime(t, minTimestamp) / timestamps.length;
  });
  
  const millisecondsFromStartOfDay = (minTimestamp + average) % ONE_DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS;
  
  return new Date(0,0,0,
                 Math.trunc(millisecondsFromStartOfDay / (3600000)),
                 Math.trunc(millisecondsFromStartOfDay % 3600000 / (60000)),
                 Math.trunc(millisecondsFromStartOfDay % 10000 / 1000));
}

function getMillisecondsFromTimeTillMinTime(time, minTime){
  if(time < minTime){
    return ONE_DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS - minTime + time;
  }
  
  return time - minTime;
}

function getTimePartInMilliseconds(t){
  return (t.getHours() * 3600 +
         t.getMinutes() * 60 +
         t.getSeconds()) * 1000 + t.getMilliseconds();
}

// The year, month and date are not relevant.
let times = [
  new Date(2020, 8, 3, 23, 30, 0),
  new Date(2020, 9, 1, 0, 30, 0),
  new Date(2020, 9, 2, 1, 30, 0)
];

console.log(calculateAverageOfHours(times, new Date(2020,8,30,22,0,0))); 
// output: Dec 31 1899 00:30:00
```

It calculates the average time relative to a minimum time(ex: if `minTime`
is 22:00 then the difference between 00:30 and `minTime` would be 02:30. On the other hand if `minTime`is 01:00 then the difference between 00:30 and `minTime` would be 23:30). The times in the array are assumed to be greater than `minTime`.

The durations between each item in the array and `minTime` are summed up and divided to the number of items in the array. This result is the average which next is added to `minTime`. The result can yield a duration greater than 24 hours so a modulo operation will cut the days and leave only the time in milliseconds.

Comment: This question was asked 7 years ago, and it it specifically about javascript. You posted an answer in c#...