# How to calculate average time of day taking into account timezone differences?

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel, datetime

I'm using Laravel/PHP/MySQL and storing all dates and times in UTC.

The user can select a timezone (for example Eastern), enter a date and time, and the date and time will be converted to UTC before storing.  On retrieval it will be converted to user's selected timezone.

My question is how can you get the average time of day from a series of records taking into account the timezone (preferably in the database query)?  The following question addresses average time of day in PHP, but not the timezone issue.

[How to calculate average time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880766/how-to-calculate-average-time)

Here is what I'm doing:

```
SEC_TO_TIME( AVG( TIME_TO_SEC( TIME(flights.departed_at) ) ) ) ) AS average_time
```

This works except for records that span daylight saving/standard time in a region that observes it.

FOR EXAMPLE: You may have a record with the UTC datetime of `2015-08-18 11:00:00` that was entered by a user in EDT at `2015-08-18 07:00:00`.  Then you have a second record entered with the UTC datetime of `2015-11-10 12:00:00` by a user in EST at `2015-11-10 07:00:00`.  If you try to calculate the average time of day it should equate to `07:00:00` but instead the result is `07:30:00`.

Any ideas how to overcome this?  Am I approaching this all wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: daylight savings. Based on the dates, one is 7 hours and one is 8. That averages to 7.5 hours.

Comment: you store everything in utc, and adjust timezones for output only. anything else will just be incredibly painful, and highly inefficient as you continually jump around between timezones like a drunk flea.

Comment: @MarcB That is what I'm doing.  I convert user input from ETD or EST to UTC, store it then display it as ETD or EST.  The problem is when calculating average time from a record entered in EDT and a record entered in EST, both converted to UTC.

Comment: if they're both in utc, then what's the problem? utc doesn't do daylight savings, so your edt record should've become 06:00:00 or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all your times stored in Z, and if your MySQL database has the [timezones loaded correctly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html), you can use the [zoneinfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) timezone name to retrieve your local times. For example,

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2015-08-01 11:00', 'UTC', 'America/New_York'),
       CONVERT_TZ('2015-12-01 12:00', 'UTC', 'America/New_York')
```

yields

```
 2015-08-01 07:00   2015-12-01 07:00
```

The point is, the [zoneinfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) database knows to use daylight saving time or standard time for each datetime value. It doesn't use the *current* offset, it uses the offset in effect on the date in question.

So, you can retrieve the time of day, in local time, with an expression like this:

```
TIME(CONVERT_TZ(utc_time_column, 'UTC', 'America/New_York'))
```

Then, you average those times-of-day in the usual way.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the type of solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

In short, your code is working correctly. Once the date is in UTC, you'd have to re-calculate whether or not it was entered (1) during daylight savings time, (2) by someone actually observing daylight savings time, and (3) in a place that recognizes daylight savings time.

I can really only think of one way to approach this.

Add some kind of flag when the data is saved to mark the timestamp as DST. You can use this flag to adjust for the hour difference. How you generate this flag is up to you.

Comment: This was the first approach I considered, but @OllieJones solution is more what I was looking for.  Thanks for responding!

Comment: Ah, ok. Since it wasn't mentioned in your question, I didn't want to assume that you already had TZ information stored. His answer is definitely more appropriate then.